# Как сложить значения по дням без потери остальных столбцов в таблице?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Дана таблица c измерением показателя, который может собираться несколько раз в день.

```
    Date        mark    user_id
0   19.06.2018  8.5     1122
1   21.06.2018  12.1    1122
2   21.06.2018  3.0     1122
3   21.06.2018  5.0     1122
4   29.06.2018  4.4     1545
5   30.06.2018  2.0     2156
```

Цель: Сложить показатель `mark` по дням, при этом сохранить `id` юзеров, соответствующие каждому дню.

Пробовал через `resample` и `groupby`, но ничего дельного не получилось.

Пример датафрейма:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ["19.06.2018", "21.06.2018", "21.06.2018", "21.06.2018", "29.06.2018", "30.06.2018" ],
    'user_id': [1122, 1122, 1122, 1122, 1545, 2156 ],
    'mark': [8.5, 12.1, 3, 5, 4.4, 2]
    })
```

Comment: По-моему, если вы используете Pandas то есть смысл пользоваться его преимуществами и стараться не использовать циклы. PS полагаю что ответ от  @MarianD должен быть принятым ответом в данном случае.

Comment: PS кстати, отлично сформулированный вопрос с шикарным примером данных! (+1) Было бы здорово если бы все могли так формулировать вопросы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df2 = df.groupby(["Date", "user_id"]).sum()
print(df2)
```

Вывод:

> ```
>                     mark
> Date       user_id      
> 19.06.2018 1122      8.5
> 21.06.2018 1122     20.1
> 29.06.2018 1545      4.4
> 30.06.2018 2156      2.0
> ```

---

Или

```
df2 = df.groupby(("user_id", "Date")).sum()
print(df2)
```

Вывод:

> ```
>                     mark
> user_id Date            
> 1122    19.06.2018   8.5
>         21.06.2018  20.1
> 1545    29.06.2018   4.4
> 2156    30.06.2018   2.0
> ```

---

Но а *когда вам не нужен мульти-индекс*, добавите в метод `groupby()` параметр `as_index=False` (спасибо [MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu) за его комментарий):

```
df2 = df.groupby(['user_id', 'Date'], as_index=False).sum()
print(df2)
```

и получите

> ```
>    user_id        Date  mark
> 0     1122  19.06.2018   8.5
> 1     1122  21.06.2018  20.1
> 2     1545  29.06.2018   4.4
> 3     2156  30.06.2018   2.0
> ```

Comment: Возможно автору вопроса нужен вариант без мульти-индекса, поэтому я бы добавил к ответу вариант: `df.groupby(['Date','user_id'], as_index=False).sum()` как опцию...

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо вам за полезный комментарий, добавил.

Comment: @MaxU, про индекс не знал, из-за этого никак не мог привести к нужному результату.

Comment: @kikudryavtsev, в подобных случая еще может помочь [.reset_index()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/862254/211923), но вариант с `as_index=False` является более идиоматичным...

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял, то можно например так:

```
mark = [8.5, 12.1, 3, 5, 4.4, 2]
user_id = [1122, 1122, 1122, 1122, 1545, 2156 ]
date = ["19.06.2018", "21.06.2018", "21.06.2018", "21.06.2018", "29.06.2018", "30.06.2018" ]
dict1 = {}
for i,j,k in zip(user_id, date, mark):
    if str(i)+"@"+j in dict1.keys():
        dict1[str(i)+"@"+j] = dict1[str(i)+"@"+j] + k
    else:
        dict1[str(i)+"@"+j] = k
dict1
#{'1122@19.06.2018': 8.5, '1122@21.06.2018': 20.1, '1545@29.06.2018': 4.4, '2156@30.06.2018': 2}
```

Далее там уже со словарём работайте, split по `@` и можно узнать id пользователя и дату

Ну или с кортежами - что более "питоник":

```
for i,j,k in zip(user_id, date, mark):
    t = (i, j)
    if t in dict1.keys():
        dict1[t] = dict1[t] + k
    else:
        dict1[t] = k
tt = [d + (dict1[d],) for d in dict1]
print tt
[(1122, '19.06.2018', 8.5), (1545, '29.06.2018', 4.4), (2156, '30.06.2018', 2), (1122, '21.06.2018', 20.1)]
```

Comment: `if t in dict1.keys():` может быть сокращено на `if t in dict1:`,  `dict1[t]  = dict1[t] + k` на `dict1[t] += k`.

Comment: Вместо долгого `if t in .... else: ...` вы можете просто писать единую команду `dict1[t] = dict1.get(t, 0) + k` (второй параметр метода `get()` возвратится, когда ключ `t` не существует.)

Answer (score 1):

метод [.reset_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) преобразует все столбцы (мульти-)индекса в обыкновенные столбцы DataFrame:

```
In [4]: df.groupby(['user_id','Date']).sum().reset_index()
Out[4]:
   user_id        Date  mark
0     1122  19.06.2018   8.5
1     1122  21.06.2018  20.1
2     1545  29.06.2018   4.4
3     2156  30.06.2018   2.0
```